# User authentication for web application

Tags: c#, .net, authentication

Can you please help me out with a simplest user authentication mechanism for my web application which I developed in .NET framework.

Comment: probably it would be great if you add more information in your questions. otherwise is common to observe downvotes among users. brgds!

Comment: What have you tried? What would you consider simple? What framework does your application use? What kind of users will be using your site? What type of login will they use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using MembershipProvider is very simple , check this for [further details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx)

and [This is a simple example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa.aspx)